# Unable to translate english word into indian regional language

Tags: android

I am unable to translate English words to Indian regional languages. I bought a "Translate API" key also, but I am unable to get the required output. The piece of code I am using to translate is as below:

```
Translate.DEFAULT.execute(sourceText, Language.fromString(sourceLanguageCode),
      Language.fromString(targetLanguageCode));

sourceLanguageCode=en
targetLanguageCode=hi
```

I am getting an exception at this part of code. Can anyone help in translating the English word into Indian regional languages..

Answer (score 0):

```
Translate.DEFAULT.execute(sourceText, Language.ENGLISH, Language.HINDI);
```

Comment: i also tried with above code suggested by you,but unable to get output.the error showing is as below                                                                 Error: [google-api-translate-java] Error retrieving translation.Any help please,can you please provide me a piece of code for translation.....